# Maven Error | Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: java, maven

I am unable to install/use Maven and getting the below error.

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher**

Steps on installation:

1. Downloaded Binary zip archive (3.8.5) and put it at root C:
2. Set Java Home and Maven home in system variables as **"JAVA_HOME"** and **"MAVEN_HOME"**
3. Set Path variable in system variables as **"%JAVA_HOME%\bin"** and **"C:\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin"** respectively

Now if I use **"maven -v"** command on the command line it throws the above-mentioned class error.

Also, if I use the same command in the bin directory of maven it gives results.

**P.S.** I have gone through many threads here but does not resolve my problem.

Comment: First you should use `mvn --version` and second please post the full output of that and not only excerpts...

Comment: @khmarbaise This is the only log I am getting and I used both commands "mvn -v" and "mvn --version" and the error is the same in both the cases

Comment: Remove the `MAVEN_HOME` variable because it's not needed... open a new console window and execute `mvn --version` and post the full output of that here...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your response! but no luck..I followed your steps but Same error.

Comment: Please post the full output which happens inside the window... BTW: Can you you the directory tree in `C:\apache-maven-3.8.5\` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise : There is no such more log on this. i am just getting this:

C:\Users\ritesh.kashyap>mvn --version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Comment: Do you have some environment entry like `M2*`?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to fulfil the request I made? Directory tree etc? please show them...?

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise! I put maven directory in program files and it worked with same configs with updated path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put maven directory in Program files folder and updated path and it started working!

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu I got this error when trying to update maven from 3.6.x to 3.8.x. It was resolved after I reinstall maven.

Go to maven [archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/) > select version > binaries > copy link for apache-maven-3.8.x-bin.tar.gz file

```
cd /tmp
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp
tar xvf apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz
cp -r apache-maven-3.8.6 /opt/
```

Add followings to end of **.bashrc** file

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.6
PATH="$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```